# XNA error - file not found

Tags: xna, xbox360

I am working on XNA with XML reading.  While I'm debugging the code its shows file not found error, but I added my XML file in `Content` reference folder.  While I'm using this code I got the error.

`System.IO.Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("ProductSchema");`

Thanks in advance.

Bharathi.G

Answer (score 1):

Shawn explains this very well in this post: [Shawn's blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/12/22/why-does-contentmanager-load-or-titlecontainer-openstream-say-file-not-found.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the extension:

```
System.IO.Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("ProductSchema.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether that file is present in the bin folder where your game .exe file lives (bin\Windows Phone\Debug\Content). If not, then this may be the problem. To solve this :

right click the file >> select property >> change **build action** to None and **copy to output directory** to Copy if newer.

This works for me while loading/reading binary files in my game.